# How to cast a string to numeric in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with string columns. Like `varchar` or `text`.

I want to select those values as a `tinyint` or `int`. But the following fails:

`SELECT CAST(example AS INT) FROM mytable`

Result:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INT) FROM mytable LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `signed` or `unsigned`:

```
SELECT CAST(example AS SIGNED) FROM mytable
```

I find it very strange that MySQL does not support `INT` in this context (or lengths on strings).

Also, in MySQL, implicit conversion is often used:

```
SELECT (example + 0)
```

Comment: @membersound . . . You have to ask the folks who designed MySQL and decided to deviate from standard SQL in this regard.

Comment: Excellent question and answer. @membersound I wonder whether SELECT CAST(0 AS INT) FROM mytable works for you. If so, then something has to be with the values. Otherwise something has to be with MySQL, at least your version.

Comment: I tried it on the console of a `mysql  Ver 8.0.18-9` on table `mysql.db`. It gives the same error.

Comment: @membersound this seems to mean that MySQL has a bug I was not aware of earlier. Nice catch!